# User Interface in SAS

Tags: user-interface, sas, logistic-regression

I want to build an user interface on SAS for logistic regression in which we provide the data - or upload the data with the variables and the dependent variable and it gives an output which gives us the Regression table and a few other desire metrices.

What should be the most efficient way of doing this? Does SAS have such a provision of doing it?

Comment: The SASjs framework was built for this - check out https://sasjs.io

Answer (score 2):

To add, if you know some HTML / JavaScript and have access to a SAS Stored Process Web Application (licensed with the Integration Technologies component linked to by DomPazz), we maintain a GPL licensed library that lets you very easily build modern, standard HTML5 user interfaces to your SAS analytical routines.

Have a look at [the H54s library on GitHub](http://github.com/boemska/h54s).

Answer (score 1):

There is an old SAS package called SAS/AF that allowed you to build UIs.  That package is rarely used for a number of reasons.

I have built numerous UIs for SAS in .NET connecting to SAS via a Workspace Server.  There are also libraries in Java to do the same.  Take a look at SAS Integration Technologies (http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/inttech/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use SAS EG or SAS Studio they both provide a GUI interface for various procedures. SAS Studio is relatively new, and you can write your own custom tasks for it as well.

Here's the the link to logistic regression analysis in SAS Studio. Even if you don't use it the options should give you an idea of the options that you may want to include in your GUI.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/webeditorug/67434/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1sahl3jgs8b2qn11jcr7n9vr1qd.htm